# How to set my yearChosen variable?

Tags: apex, visualforce

I set my variables like this

```
public Integer yearChosen { get; set; }
public Integer setYear {get; set;}
Integer currentYear = System.Today().year();
yearChosen = currentYear;        


public List<SelectOption> getItems()
{
List<SelectOption> options = new List<SelectOption>();
// Make the first choice generic message
options.add(new SelectOption('2015','2015'));
options.add(new SelectOption('2016','2016'));
options.add(new SelectOption('2017','2017'));
options.add(new SelectOption('2018','2018'));
return options;
}
```

and my vf page has this

```
    <strong>Please Select a Year:</strong>
    <apex:selectList id="yearChosen" value="{!yearChosen}" multiselect="false" size="1">
        <apex:selectOptions value="{!Items}"/>
    </apex:selectList>
    <apex:commandButton action="{!setYear}" value="Go"/>
<p />
```

what to put in my setYear method in order to set the yearChosen variable to the year that the user chooses instead of the current year which you can see from my code is the default?

Comment: whenever user will select any value in picklist. value will be update to yearChosen variable. just debug the value in setYear method. you will get the selected value

Comment: Make this an answer and I will mark it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So looks like you need to some clarification.

### How it works

whenever user will select any value in picklist. The value will be update to yearChosen variable.

just debug the value in `setYear` method. you will get the selected value.